# How can I delete duplicates without removing my formula other columns?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my simple form:

```
Col A:       Col B:    Col C:                       Col D:
010Mar0100   Link      =mid(A2,find(".",A2)-10,10)  =vlookup(C2,MAIN!B:B,1,false)
010Mar0110   Link      =mid(A3,find(".",A3)-10,10)  =vlookup(C3,MAIN!B:B,1,false)
020Mar0100   Link      =mid(A4,find(".",A4)-10,10)  =vlookup(C4,MAIN!B:B,1,false)
020Mar0100   Link      =mid(A5,find(".",A5)-10,10)  =vlookup(C5,MAIN!B:B,1,false)
030Mar0100   Link      =mid(A6,find(".",A6)-10,10)  =vlookup(C6,MAIN!B:B,1,false)
```

Col C and D has formula which return value I need.
Col A and B get refresh daily

I wanted to add a script to remove duplicates without removing my formula in col C and D

Every time I use this script it does that.

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
 var rng = sheet.getRange("A2:B")
var data = rng.getValues();
var newData = new Array();
for(i in data){
var row = data[i];
var duplicate = false;
for(j in newData){
  if(row.join() == newData[j].join()){
    duplicate = true;
  }
}
if(!duplicate){
  newData.push(row);
}
}
rng.clearContents();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, 
newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

What Do I need to change to get it to just focus on Col A and B only?

Comment: just delete the duplicate rows.

Comment: Try recording a macro using inbuilt removeDuplicates?

Comment: I think that there is not method of `clearContents()`, and in the case of `getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length)`, the values are put to the 1st row. In this case, how about modifying to `clearContent()` and `getRange(2, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length)`? By the way, about `change to get it to just focus on Col A and B only`, I think that in your modified script, the columns "A" and "B" are modified without modifying the columns "C" and "D". Is this situation the result you expect? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

Use inbuilt  [removeDuplicates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#removeDuplicates()):

```
const remD = () =>
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheetByName('Data')
    .getRange('A2:B')
    .removeDuplicates();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solutions**

What you want to do boils down to filtering out non-unique elements from a list. If I understand correctly that you want to preserve columns `C` and `D` intact, you just need to make your logic clearer by introducing a helper function (btw, `includes` requires [switching to V8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration) if that's not a new project) and `setValues` on the same `rng` (see below improvement 3)

```js
/**
 * Removes duplicates
 * @param {any[]} array 2D input
 * @returns {any[]} filtered input
 */
const filterDuplicates = (array) => {
  const stack = [];
  
  return array.filter(elem => {
    const joined = elem.join('');
    
    if( stack.includes(joined) ) {
      return false;
    }
    
    stack.push(joined);
  
    return true;
  });
};

const [ input, output, tbody, tbody_init ] = document.querySelectorAll('#input, #output, #grid_init, #grid');

const buildCellGrid = (parent, grid) => {
  parent.innerHTML = '';

  for(const row of grid) {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    
    for(const cell of row) {
      const td = document.createElement('td');
      td.textContent = cell;
      tr.append(td);
    }
    
    parent.append(tr);
  }
};

input.addEventListener('change',event=> {
  const { value } = event.target;
  
  const parsedVal = JSON.parse(value);
  
  const filtered = filterDuplicates(parsedVal);
  
  output.textContent = JSON.stringify(filtered, null, '');
  
  buildCellGrid(tbody_init, filtered);
 
  buildCellGrid(tbody, parsedVal);
});
```

```css
p, textarea {
  margin: 0 2vw; 
}

textarea {
  padding: 2vh 2vw;
  line-height: 2;
  resize: none;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
}

table {
  margin: 2vh 2vw;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  padding: 1vh;
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<p>
Enter valid 2D Array
</p>
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>

<table>
  <caption>Initial</caption>
  <tbody id="grid_init"></tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <caption>Filtered</caption>
  <tbody id="grid"></tbody>
</table>
```

**Improvements**

1. You can switch from calling `Array` constructor (`new Array()`) to a more common and less verbose literal notation `[]`. The only interesting feature of it is allocating an empty `Array` of N length with `new Array(N)` (I sometimes use it with `fill(whatever_value)`).
2. Don't use `for...in` on arrays - this statement has its own use (with `Object`s). Please, use `for...of` that is tailored for the job.
3. You don't need to `getRange()` new `Range` for updated values since they are by definition a subgrid of original values and you preemptively clear the range with `clearContents()` [I believe [you meant](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) `clearContent()`].

**Notes**

1. If you are interested, here is a semi-interactive comparison of approaches to creating a new `Array` instance:

```js
const li = (parent) => (txt) => {
  const elem = document.createElement('li');
  elem.textContent = txt || 'undefined';
  parent.append(elem);
}

const forAll = (...args) => (callback) => {
  for(const arg of args) {
    callback(arg);
  }
};

const genConstrArr = (numElems) => {
  const temp = [];
 
  let i = 0;
  while(i < numElems) {
    temp.push(`${i++} elem`);
  }
  
  return new Array(...temp);
};

const genArr = (numElems) => {
  const arr = [];
  
  let i = 0;
  while(i < numElems) {
    arr.push(`${i++} elem`);
  }
  
  return arr;
};

const buildList = (container, array) => {
  const lists = container.querySelectorAll('ul');
  const [inList, ofList, keysList, ownList, symList] = lists;
  
  forAll(...lists)(list => list.innerHTML = '');
  
  for(const key in array) {
    li(inList)(key);
  }

  forAll(...array)( li(ofList) );

  const emptyKeys = Object.keys(array);
  forAll(...emptyKeys)( li(keysList) );

  const names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(array);
  forAll(...names)( li(ownList) );

  const symbols = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(array);
  forAll(...symbols)( li(symList) );

  forAll(...lists)(list => !list.hasChildNodes() && li(list)('[Empty]')); 
};

const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('#constructor, #constructor_filled, #literal');

const form = document.forms.array_control;
form.addEventListener('change', event => {
  const { value } = event.target;

  buildList(boxes[0], new Array(+value));  
  buildList(boxes[1], genConstrArr(+value));
  buildList(boxes[2], genArr(+value));
});
```

```css
input {
  margin: 4vh 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2vh 2vw;
}

td {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<form id="array_control">
  <label for="elems">Number of elements:</label>
  <input id="elems" min="0" name="elems" type="number" />
</form>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>for...in</th>
      <th>for...of</th>
      <th>Object.keys()</th>
      <th>getOwnPropertyNames()</th>
      <th>getOwnPropertySymbols()</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
    <tr id="constructor">
      <th>Constructor (1 arg)</th>

      <td><ul></ul></td>
      <td><ul></ul></td>
      <td><ul></ul></td>
      <td><ul></ul></td>
      <td><ul></ul></td>
    </tr>    
  
    <tr id="constructor_filled">
      <th>Constructor (>1 arg)</th>

      <td><ul></ul></td>
      <td><ul></ul></td>
      <td><ul></ul></td>
      <td><ul></ul></td>
      <td><ul></ul></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="literal">
      <th>Literal</th>

      <td><ul></ul></td>
      <td><ul></ul></td>
      <td><ul></ul></td>
      <td><ul></ul></td>
      <td><ul></ul></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**References**

1. JS [Lexical grammar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Array_literals) on MDN
2. [Enumerability and ownership](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) of properties
3. `Set` built-in [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) on MDN
4. `for...in` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and `for...of` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) on MDN

Answer (score 1):

Add a column after column D and add this function in that column. It will basically add Unique/Duplicate text to the row that is unique or double, based on the values in col A and col B. You can use even ArrayFormula before If function

=ArrayFormula(IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A1,A1, $B$1:$B1,B1)=1, "Unique", "Duplicate"))

Once you have this col filled you can filter only the rows that have "unique" on col E and you will have all your unique rows with your formulas unchanged

Now, just to be honest, I took this info online. I tried to research it to use for reference but couldn't find again.

Answer (score 1):

`getValues()` returns a 2D array. If you want to remove duplicate rows, you have to remove the inner arrays — the elements of the outer array — that are duplicates).

You can do that using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), like this:

```js
function removeDuplicates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var rng = sheet.getRange("A2:B")
  var data = rng.getValues();
  var uniqueRows = data.reduce((unique, row) => {
    var duplicate = unique.some(uniqueRow => JSON.stringify(uniqueRow) === JSON.stringify(row));
    if (!duplicate) unique.push(row);
    return unique;
  }, []);
  rng.clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, uniqueRows.length, uniqueRows[0].length).setValues(uniqueRows);
}
```

After getting the array of unique rows (called `uniqueRows`), you just have to:

- Remove all previous contents in the range with [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) (not `clearContents()`).
- Write the `uniqueRows` to your sheet with `setValues`.

#### Note:

- You have to [enable V8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime) for this script to work.

#### Reference:

- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)